# How to get 3D world space position from Render Texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am using  [**Render Texture**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) to make a **Side Map**, it is working fine and I have made it through these steps.

1. One Main Camera Rendering the Scene.
2. NGUI Camera Rendering the GUI.
3. That GUI contains the Render Texture (minimap) which rendering the scene on the texture using GUI Camera.

**But** now I want to improve the map further and want it to make intractable. I want world space position from Render Texture click point. **Is there any way available that I get world space position from render texture's specific click point?**

If I click somewhere in render texture then, how can I get the point in 3D world space.

*For example: I clicked a car object on Render Texture. Now, how can I highlight or get it in 3D world space.?* How can Convert 2D render texture click position to World Space Position!

Comment: Pointer interactions don't happen on individual textures, they are the result of a raycast from the camera hitting a collider. Your game object will need a collider if you're using Unity5 you can use the EventSystem a [PhysicsRaycaster](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) on the camera & the [IPointClickHander](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) interface

Comment: i guess raycast use physics and there is not physics applied on camera

Comment: how do we i get world space position from texture click?

Comment: Raycasts are part of the physics system yes, but they are cast from Camera. I recommend you read the documentation :). You need a collider on your game object that has the render texture plane, then use a raycast. A quick google search gives a few examples over on the Unity3d answers, have a look at [this thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1018336/is-there-a-way-to-click-on-a-render-texture-to-sel.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/411812/raycasting-and-render-texture.html)

Comment: If you need help with actual implementation please update your question with some actual code that you're having the specific issue with.

Comment: no i dont know how to do this? how to get world space position from the render texture. is this possible?

Comment: your links something similar to my problem

Comment: attach collider to your render texture gameobject. cast a ray against it and store the hitpoint in texture space. next find the camera the texture uses and using the previously stored hitpoint, shoot a 2nd ray from the viewport corresponding to the texture coordinate. whatever is hit by the 2nd ray should be the correct object. (untested)

Comment: @yes this untested trick doesn't giving me the accurate position of point. what to do

Comment: how off is it? or how is it off. i mean in where exactly does it fail? have you tried drawing debug rays using `Debug.DrawRay(start, direction, color, duration)` (if dont use the overload where you can set a duration, the ray will only appear for a single frame which is too short to see)? im not at home atm, so i cannot try it out myself for another few hours.

Answer (score 4):

This assumes some things.

First i use EventSystems to get mouse clicks. This is no requirement, it can be changed easily (by you though ^^). To set it up correctly, you need an `EventSystem` in your scene (if you have a UI, you probably have one already).

Second you need to attach a `PhysicsRaycaster` component to your main camera (the camera the player sees through).

Lastly, on the GameObject which contains the renderer for the render texture (i used a simple quad) you apply the below script and assign the corresponding camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

//i chose box collider because its cheap
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class RenderTextureRaycaster : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler {

    //assign in inspector
    public Camera portalExit;

    BoxCollider portal;
    Vector3 portalExitSize;

    void Start() {
        portal = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        //this is the target camera resolution, idk if there is another way to get it.
        portalExitSize = new Vector3(portalExit.targetTexture.width, portalExit.targetTexture.height, 0);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData) {
        //the click in world space
        Vector3 worldClick = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
        //transformed into local space
        Vector3 localClick = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldClick);
        //since the origin of the collider is in its center, we need to offset it by half its size to get it realtive to bottom left
        Vector3 textureClick = localClick + portal.size / 2;
        //now we scale it up by the actual texture size which equals to the "camera resoution"
        Vector3 rayOriginInCameraSpace = Vector3.Scale(textureClick, portalExitSize);

        //with this knowledge we can creata a ray.
        Ray portaledRay = portalExit.ScreenPointToRay(rayOriginInCameraSpace );
        RaycastHit raycastHit;

        //and cast it.
        if (Physics.Raycast(portaledRay, out raycastHit)) {
            Debug.DrawLine(portaledRay.origin, raycastHit.point, Color.blue, 4);
        }
        else {
            Debug.DrawRay(portaledRay.origin, portaledRay.direction * 100, Color.red, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

edit: above maybe is a bit verbose, you could reduce it easily if you like one liners, its just to show how it works. also please only *consider this a proof of concept, its not thoroughly tested*.

Comment: please mention all steps and let me revized you that I have an image which is render texture using as a minimap. from this minimap (2D) i want to get the world space position. That if i click on image some where then i get the position in the scene.

Comment: hope this clarification will help you!

Comment: your this scene completely demanding the change in my hirarchy

Comment: well, im sorry, i have no clue about NGUI whatsover. why dont you use the unity ui, since 4.6 (i think) its pretty awesome. but it basically should follow the same logic. as soon as you know where you are in the texture relative to its left-bottom point, you can derive the position on the screen of the camera. the camera of the render texture has the same resulation as the render texture it renders to.

Comment: Ok i will use it but the problem still persist .

Comment: well im sure there is some sort of callback for NGUI which tells you where in a certain element you clicked. is there some sort of OnClick function or OnPointerOver or anything like that?

Comment: forget about ngui i am use ur simple code in simple screen but no progress even line is not drawing

Comment: OnPointerDown is not calling why?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan check if you have an EventSystem in your scene and the Script attached to the correct gameobject (the quad with the render texture). also your players camera needs a PhysicsRaycaster. This is the setup i used to try it out http://imgur.com/7kUWGYZ

Comment: but if you want to use this as part of the standard unity gui, its even simpler, you can easily get the local coordinates from a rect transform with  `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(..)`

Comment: i was waiting for you to show me your setup. maybe my reply should have been a pun. anyway, would you show me your setup?